# proximal to, distal to , next to?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What does '' to '' mean in the examples I gave below ? Which item in dictionaries does it correspond to? I couldn't understand.

Elbow is **distal to the shoulder.**

Elbow is **proximal to the wrist.**

Put a phone charger **next to your bed**

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/to

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/to_1?q=to

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/to

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/to

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to

Comment: It might help us answer better if we knew how you're going to apply this information. It's likely that whatever context you want it for, it's possible to do what you want without having a specific dictionary definition.

Comment: "Distal" and "proximal" aren't common vocabulary; most English speakers, if they know these words at all, would consider them medical _jargon_.  I wouldn't advise learners to use these words other than in technical anatomical contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Prepositions are "function" words, primarily relevant to ***syntax / grammar*** rather than ***semantics / meaning***. But preposition "to" often implies (spatial or metaphoric) *relationship / proximity* of some kind.

OP's "distal" and "proximal" examples would *always* be "literal" spatial relationships, but in something like *Cleanliness is **next to** godliness*, it's more figurative.

You might find it helpful to note that ***near, by, alongside, beside,*** for example, are all alternatives that could "more or less" replace "to" in your contexts.

Answer (score 2):

From Merriam-Webster, this is the closest:

**1 e** —used as a function word to indicate relative position
*// perpendicular to the floor*

It appears that this might be correct as in both phrases we can insert "relative" before "to" and maintain its meaning and grammaticality:

> perpendicular **relative** to the floor
> distal **relative** to the shoulder

"Next to" is a different structure, as we cannot insert "relative":

> <del>next **relative** to your bed</del>

Some linguists argue that "next to" is a two-word preposition, with the same function and syntax as the preposition "beside" in terms of describing relative physical location. I can't find any links to support this claim, but if this is true, then it means "to" in the context of "next to the bed" isn't a word on its own, and so doesn't have a definition.